# Drag and Drop function works fine when ran unelevated but not when ran as administator

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, mvvm-light

So I have set up a drag and drop function on a ListView in wpf like so

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" 
xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras"

<ListView>
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
       <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding DropFiles}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

and in my view Model I have

```
    private RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> _dropFiles;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the DropFiles.
    /// </summary>
    public RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> DropFiles
    {
        get
        {
            return _dropFiles
                ?? (_dropFiles = new RelayCommand<DragEventArgs>(
                args =>
                {
                  //Do Something with args
                }));
        }
    }
```

This works fine in debug mode, but when I deploy this version I get the following icon appear when I try to drag and drop my files into the listview:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why this may be?

**UPDATE**

If I run my project as administrator, the drag and drop feature is broken as described where as if I run my project not as administrator the drag and drop feature works fine. Why would this be?

Comment: Where are you deploying to

Comment: Windows 8.1 machine. debug on windows 8

Comment: Deploy as in clickonce?

Comment: No, I am just copying and pasting the debug folder to my client machine

Comment: See if youre app is running in partial trust  and set it to full trust

Comment: Permissions tab in the properties window of your project

Comment: I can't see a permissions tab in my properties window of my project. If I run my project under administrator mode the drag and drop feature doesn't work. It only works when ran not as administrator? (I must also add that my project is a plugin application)

Comment: Surely a permission problem somewhere

Comment: Indeed. Although I would have expected it to be the other way round where administrator mode fixes the issue instead of breaks it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I don't fully understand this but it looks like security is the issue

> **User Interface Privilege Isolation (UIPI)**
>
> Okay, back to our drag and
> drop issue… A “sister” technology that works in conjunction with MIC
> is UIPI.  UIPI blocks Windows messages being sent from process with a
> lower MIC level to one running at a higher MIC level. Drag-and-drop is
> implemented via Windows messages.  Therefore, if you try and
> drag-and-drop a file from Windows Explorer (medium MIC) to Notepad
> running elevated (high MIC), the Windows messages are blocked and
> drag-and-drop doesn’t work.
>
> You can use ChangeWindowsMessageFilterEx in your application to allow
> specified Windows messages to not be blocked. Unfortunately, this
> isn’t recommended as a safe solution for drag and drop due to the
> messages that drag and drop uses.
>
> **Okay. Now What?**
>
> The best solution is to only use drag and drop between
> the same MIC levels. With UAC enabled, Windows Explorer will run at a
> medium MIC level.  Therefore, your application (Notepad in our
> example) needs to run at medium (or lower) MIC level.  The bottom line
> is that drag and drop from Windows Explorer will not work if your
> application is elevated.  If you find yourself in this situation, you
> may need to rethink your application design or not support
> drag-and-drop with UAC enabled.

Taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patricka/archive/2010/01/28/q-why-doesn-t-drag-and-drop-work-when-my-application-is-running-elevated-a-mandatory-integrity-control-and-uipi.aspx